# Merge multiple Sass maps

Tags: merge, sass, maps

I have three Sass maps that I want to merge into one map. With the map-merge function I can only merge two maps together. How can I merge more than two maps?

A shortened example of my situation:

```
    $color-name: (
        blue: (
            default: blue,
            dark: navy,
            light: sky
        )
    );

    $color-event: (
        danger: (
            default: set($color-name, red),
            dark: set($color-name, red, dark),
            light: set($color-name, red, light),
        )
    );

    $color-category: (
        heading: (
            default: set($color-name, grey),
            dark: set($color-name, grey, dark),
            light: set($color-name, grey, light)
        )
    );

    $color: map-merge($color-name, $color-event, $color-category);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If map-merge takes 2 mappings and returns a single mapping, but you have 3 mappings... you use map-merge twice.

```
$color: map-merge(map-merge($color-name, $color-event), $color-category);
```

Answer (score 35):

*I realize this is a bit late, but since this was the only solution I could find while googling I want to post this for others looking for a similar solution.*

I stumbled upon this question trying to find the same answer, and while @cimmanon's answer may work for your specific example of combining only 3 maps, it isn't a good solution if you wanted to combine, say 10 maps. I wanted a solution that could be applied to 3 maps or 50. So I wrote a function to handle merging multiple maps together:

```
@function map-collect($maps...) {
  $collection: ();

  @each $map in $maps {
    $collection: map-merge($collection, $map);
  }
  @return $collection;
}
```

And use it like so:

```
$colors: map-collect($color-name, $color-event, $color-category);
```

Since this uses the `map-merge` function, SASS 3.3+ is required.

Comment: Hi jlego, great function. Thanks for sharing! You put the cherry on the cake ;)

Comment: Nice contribution!

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap has its own multiple map merge function:

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color/#generating-utilities
- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/323f9d6f687ab148da4ad074e0eddef8ab3b132b/scss/_functions.scss#L100C1-L107C2

I've added it here for reference, but as you'll notice it's the same as the one from [biggles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/664904/biggles)

```
@function map-merge-multiple($maps...) {
  $merged-maps: ();

  @each $map in $maps {
    $merged-maps: map-merge($merged-maps, $map);
  }
  @return $merged-maps;
}
```