# Merge multiple sass maps returns type string not map

Tags: sass, sass-maps

Similar to this idea, I created a helper method to merge multiple sass maps.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30740182/6413673

My Helper code as follows:

```
@function map-merge-all($maps...) {
  $result: ();

  @each $map in $maps {
    $result: map-merge($result, $map);
  }
  @return $result;
}
```

My issue is, that its not returning a map, instead its returning a string.

```
$params : map-merge-all($mapA,$mapB,$mapC);
@warn "$mapA type is:"+type-of($mapA);
@warn "$mapB type is:"+type-of($mapB);
@warn "$mapC type is:"+type-of($mapC);
@warn "$param type is:"+type-of($params);
```

Output is :

```
WARNING: $mapA type is:map
WARNING: $mapB type is:map
WARNING: $mapB type is:map
WARNING: $params type is:string
```

Any ideas as to what is wrong with my helper method?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the method is fine, my issue was that I was not calling the @import method for my helper file, so it was in fact not even calling the map-merge-all method.